# Persist some attributes with redux-persist does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

I create the store of my app:

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';
import createFilter from 'redux-persist-transform-filter';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from './rootReducer';

const whiteListFilter = createFilter('references', 'label');

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  whiteListFilter,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
const persistor = persistStore(store);


export {store, persistor};
```

and the referenceSlice.js:

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"


const initialState = {
label: '',
references: [],
error: '',
}

const referenceSlice = createSlice({
name: 'reference',
initialState,
reducers: {
 updateReference(state, action){
  state = Object.assign(state, action.payload);
}
}
});

export default referenceSlice.reducer;
export const {updateReference} = referenceSlice.actions
```

Presentation.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {updateReference} from 'referenceSlice';


const Presenter = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [label, setLabel] = React.useState('');
const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
const [touched, setTouched] = React.useState(false);

const handleChange = (e) => {
 setLabel(e.target.value);
}

const handleBlur = (e) => {
 setTouched(true)
if(e.target.value) {
  dispatch(updateReference(label));
}else {
 setError('required*')
}
}

return(
 <div>
   <TextField
     label='Reference label'
     onChange={handleChange}
     onBlur={handleBlur}
     helperText={touched && error ? error : ''}
    />
   <OtherComponent />
</div>
);

export default Presenter;
```

The problem here that I want to persist only some attributes from the references reducer but the whole reducer was persisted in this case. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Redux-persist is looking for an array in the whitelist filter, these need to be the key names in your rootReducer.

See https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#blacklist--whitelist

```
// WHITELIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['navigation'] // only navigation will be persisted
};
```

Also useful to note that blacklisting nested attributes is possible, just done in a bit weird way where you need to blacklist the full reducer, and create a separate config for the blacklisted reducer which blacklists only some attributes.

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#nested-persists

Comment: I tried it but does not fix the issue, the whole reducer was stored in the local storage not only the mentioned attributes that I want to persist.

Comment: This does not work.